# Is there a good practice to name kotlin file contains only functions?

Tags: kotlin, naming-conventions, naming

For example i have a kotlin file with validation functions. Another example is a file with only one function which gets mobile device data (manufacturer, android version, etc.)

I have some thoughts to name it like for validation functions ValidationUtils.kt or ValidationFunctions.kt, Validations.kt, ValidationFun.kt, and for second example DeviceDataUtil.kt, DeviceDataProvider.kt (it sounds like a class name), DeviceDataGetterFun.kt.

I think they all suck. Can u help?

Comment: The official conventions are here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names

Comment: …according to which just about all the proposed names would be acceptable.

Comment: My _opinion_ is ValidationUtils with many in one - but be prepared for this question to be struck off, since questions that seek opinion-based answers are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the four basic kinds of modules in modular programming languages are

1. Package of functions (no state)
2. Abstract Data Structure (state with one instance)
3. Abstract Data Type (state with several instances)
4. Class (state with several instances and polymorphism)

What you describe is an example of the first kind. One sensible convention is to use an **abstract noun** which describes the concept, so simply *Validation* would be a good choice. If you had a collection of mathematical functions you would name it *Math* and so on.